# how to select the "td tag" by getElementById

Tags: html

```
<script>

    alert(document.getElementById('a'));

</script>
<html>
    <table>
    <tr>
     <td id='a' class="test">test</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

I tried this but get the "null" as a result.
anyone can help?
Thanks~

Comment: When your script is getting executed, the element with that `id` hasn't been populated on the page yet! Hence, null result.

Comment: Always call javascript at the end of a html page or if the page is loaded (onload in body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
    <table>
    <tr>
     <td id='a' class="test">test</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<script>

    alert(document.getElementById('a'));

</script>
</html>
```

have script tag below the `<td>`. Null is because you are trying to have a which is not there when script gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                alert(document.getElementById('a'));
                clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
            }
        }, 10);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <tr>
         <td id='a' class="test">test</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `document.readyState` is a property built into all browsers to check if the page has loaded or not.

More info about the `readyState` property:

- [Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/extensions-api-tab-readystate/)
- [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.readyState)
- [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms534359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)